# Nuxt Auth Module Authenticated User Data

Tags: authentication, vuex, nuxt.js

I have an API `api/auth` that is used to log users in. It expects to receive an `access_token` (as URL query, from Headers, or from request body), a `username`, and a `password`. I've been using the Vue Chrome Developer Tool and even though I get a `201` response from the server, the `auth.loggedIn` state is still false. I think that might be the reason why my `redirect` paths on the `nuxt.config.js` isn't working as well. Can anyone point me to the right direction on why it doesn't work?

This is a screenshot of the Vue Chrome Developer Tool
[image]

This is the JSON response of the server after logging in. The token here is different from the `access_token` as noted above.

```
{
    "token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "user": {
        "user_name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "uid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "user_data": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant part of `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
    ['bootstrap-vue/nuxt', { css: false }]
  ],
  router: {
    middleware: [ 'auth' ]
  },
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/api/auth?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'token'
          },
          logout: {
            url: '/api/auth/logout',
            method: 'post'
          },
          user: {
            url: '/api/users/me',
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: 'user'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/',
      logout: '/',
      home: '/home'
    },
    token: {
      name: 'token'
    },
    cookie: {
      name: 'token'
    },
    rewriteRedirects: true
  },
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:9000/'
  }
}
```

And my `store/index.js`

```
export const state = () => ({
  authUser: null
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_USER: function (state, user) {
    state.authUser = user
  }
}

export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    if (req.session && req.user) {
      commit('SET_USER', req.user)
    }
  },

  async login ({ commit }, { username, password }) {
    const auth = {
      username: username,
      password: password
    }

    try {
      const { user } = this.$auth.loginWith('local', { auth })
      commit('SET_USER', user)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }
}
```

The login action in the store is triggered by this method in the page:

```
export default {
  auth: false,
  methods: {
    async login () {
      try {
        await this.$store.dispatch('login', {
          username: this.form.email,
          password: this.form.password
        })
      } catch (err) {
        this.alert.status = true
        this.alert.type = 'danger'
        this.alert.response = err
      }
    }
  }
}
```

P.S. I realize I'm explicitly including the `access_token` in the URL. Currently, I don't know where a `master_key` or the like can be set in the Nuxt Auth Module.

Comment: Maybe this post help you https://medium.com/@anas.mammeri/vue-2-firebase-how-to-build-a-vue-app-with-firebase-authentication-system-in-15-minutes-fdce6f289c3c

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = () => new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    authUser: null
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_USER: function (state, user) {
      state.authUser = user
    }
  },
  actions: {
    CHECK_AUTH: function(token, router) {
      if (token === null) {
        router.push('/login')
      }
    }
  }
})
export default store
```

And for the router, this should work globally:

```
$nuxt._router.push('/')
```